# I created a Laravel Application the data is not getting stored in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, wamp

I have created a Laravel Application, where I'm trying to store images in gallery database of my dashboard, where the images are displayed in gallery page of my website, the data is not getting stored in the database. How to fix it.

This is my gallery controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Models\Gallery;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
         $gallery = Gallery::orderBy('priority')->get();
         return view('gallery', compact('gallery'));
    }

    
    public function index()
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::all();
        return view('gallery.index', compact('gallery'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('gallery.create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'priority' => 'required|integer',
        ]);
    
        $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('gallery', 'public');
        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"));
        $image->save();
    
        $newPriority = $request->priority;
    
        // Shift the priorities of existing images greater than or equal to the new priority
        Gallery::where('priority', '>=', $newPriority)
            ->orderBy('priority', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->each(function ($image) {
                $image->priority += 1;
                $image->save();
            });
    
        $gallery = new Gallery();
        $gallery->title = $request->title;
        $gallery->image = $imagePath;
        $gallery->priority = $newPriority;
        $gallery->save();
    
        return redirect()->route('gallery.index')->with('success', 'Image added successfully.');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
        return view('gallery.show', compact('gallery'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
        return view('gallery.edit', compact('gallery'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
    
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'priority' => 'required|integer',
        ]);
    
        $newPriority = $request->priority;
    
        // Check if the new priority already exists in other images
        $existingImage = Gallery::where('priority', $newPriority)->first();
    
        if ($existingImage) {
            // Shift the priority of existing images greater than or equal to the new priority
            Gallery::where('priority', '>=', $newPriority)
                ->where('id', '!=', $gallery->id)
                ->orderBy('priority', 'desc')
                ->get()
                ->each(function ($image) {
                    $image->priority += 1;
                    $image->save();
                });
    
            // Update the priority of the current image
            $gallery->priority = $newPriority;
        } else {
            // If the new priority is unique, update the priority of the current image
            $gallery->priority = $newPriority;
        }
    
        $gallery->title = $request->title;
        $gallery->save();
    
        return redirect()->route('gallery.index')->with('success', 'Image updated successfully.');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $gallery = Gallery::findOrFail($id);
    
        // Delete the image file from the storage folder
        Storage::delete('public/' . $gallery->image);
    
        $gallery->delete();
    
        return redirect()->route('gallery.index')->with('success', 'Image deleted successfully.');
    }
        
}
```

this is the form I'm using to store images in db

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <h1 class="justify-content-center">Gallery</h1>

        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif

        <form action="{{ route('gallery.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <label for="image"> Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <label for="priority">Priority</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority" value="{{ old('priority') }}" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Image</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: Have Define the "fillable" property in your Eloquent model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'image', 'priority'];
}

Comment: @ShyamDev The fillable property is needed only for mass assignment. It's not needed in the code here.

Comment: You'll need to do some troubleshooting and tracking. For instance, you say it's not being saved in the database, but is the image actually being uploaded? Does the file exist in the folder once you've submitted the form? Have you checked the error logs to see if there is anything logged there?

Comment: @aynber I've already tested it the image is not getting sent anywhere in any folder in my application

Comment: Then the issue isn't with the database code. As far as I can tell, the form should submit and pass validation. Try `Log::info($request->all());` before the validation, then add some logging lines after the validation, such as `Log::info(__LINE__);` or `Log::info('validated');`. These will be written to your log file in `storage/logs`. Use that to find out exactly how far the code is going and what might be happening.

Comment: @aynber ok I'll try it and this is my volunteer controller which I'm using to upload images of volunteers in database and it is working perfectly i used this same method for gallery but for some reason its not working